# changing displayed value upon change

Tags: java, javafx, binding

Im trying to update the value my text_counter displays based on a change of the value. How do I achieve this? I've read somewhere on SO about binding it, but I have no clue what to bind it to. Anyone that can help me out?

```
public class main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

Button button;
Button button2;
Counter counter = new Counter(0);
Text text_counter = new Text(Integer.toString(counter.getCount()));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Counter Window");

    button = new Button();
    button2 = new Button();
    button.setText("Reset");
    button.setOnAction(this);
    button2.setText("Tick");
    button2.setOnAction(this);
    button.setTranslateY(-120);
    button2.setTranslateY(-120);
    button2.setTranslateX(50);
    text_counter.textProperty().bind(counter.getCount());
```

Comment: What is the type of `Counter` ?

Comment: its a Counter object. Holds 1 private variable count

Comment: Where does it come from? Is it a class you created? If so - you can have the count be a property (`IntegerProperty` or `LongProperty`, for example). Then again, if that's all it does, you may as well use a `SimpleIntegerProperty` etc. to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the `textProperty()` of your `Text` *node* to the value of your *counter*. Here is an example of how you can proceed:

```
class Counter {
    // The StringProperty to whom the Text node's textProperty will be bound to
    private StringProperty counter; 

    public Counter() {
        counter = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public Counter(int count) {
        this();
        counter.set(Integer.toString(count));
    }

    public void set(int count) {
        counter.set(Integer.toString(count));
    }
}
```

The binding test:

```
// Create the counter
Counter c = new Counter(0);

// The Text node
Text text_counter = new Text(c.counter.get());

// Bind textProperty() to c.counter, which is a StringProperty
// Any changes to the value of c.counter will be reflected on the
// text of your Text node
text_counter.textProperty().bind(c.counter);

System.out.println("Before change:");
System.out.println(String.format("Text: %s Counter: %s",
        text_counter.textProperty().get(),
c.counter.get()));

c.counter.set("10"); // Make a change

System.out.println("After change:");
System.out.println(String.format("Text: %s Counter: %s",
        text_counter.textProperty().get(),
c.counter.get()));
```

Output:

```
Before change:
Text: 0 Counter: 0
After change:
Text: 10 Counter: 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It took me a while to figure out what you were doing as im used to python and ive only just started learning Java but I not understand how it works. Thanks!